# Rails3 help with joins scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have simple Order - Item app.  No cart.  Need help with joined scopes for my reports.

Item is polymorphic (`belongs_to :itemable, :polymorphic => true`) with Products, Services and Policies.  Policies belongs to Vendor.

**Goal is list out how much was sold by Vendor but still be able to use the scopes for Orders as seen below.**

Scopes in my Orders model

```
scope :closed_today, lambda { where("closed_date IS NOT ? AND closed_date >= ? AND closed_date < ?", nil, Time.now.midnight, Time.now.midnight.tomorrow)}
scope :closed_yesterday, lambda { where("closed_date IS NOT ? AND closed_date >= ? AND closed_date < ?", nil, Time.now.midnight.yesterday, Time.now.midnight)}
...
```

Something like - *Guess  in Orders Model?*

```
scope :with_policies, joins(:items).where(:itemable_type => "Policy")
```

And Final Result being able to group by vendor and get amounts sold.

```
<% for v in @orders.closed_today.with_policies.group("itemable.vendor_id") %>
  <%= v.somehow_get_to.vendor.name %> Sold: <%= v.somehow_get_to.collect.sum(&:price) %>
```

Price is the item field that holds how much that item sold for.

I know you can't group as shown above, so any pointers on how to do that would be great.  Would like to avoid adding vendor_id to my Items table.

---

UPDATE

Here is what I ended up doing.
Added vendor_id to items.  Made my life easier.  Sure this is a better way of doing this.

In my Items model

```
scope :in_orders_with, lambda { |orders, type| where('itemable_type IS ?', type).joins(:order) & orders }
```

In my view (since @orders.closed_today is actually passed in from another view.)

```
<% orders = @orders.closed_today %>
<p>
<% @items = Item.in_orders_with(orders, "Policy") %>
<% if !@items.blank? %>
  <% @items.group_by{ |o| o.vendor }.each do |vendor, items| %>
   <%= vendor.name %> <br />Qty Sold:<%= items.count %> Dollars Sold:<%= items.collect.sum(&:price) %><br /><br />
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  Nothing to report from Policies<br />
<% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @orders.closed_today.with_policies.group_by{|o| o.itemable.vendor}.each do |vendor, orders| %>
  <%= vendor.name %> SOLD: <%= orders.sum(&:price) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: SO Close.  o.itemable.vendor is not working, having to force it like this o.items.last.itemable.vendor.

Comment: SHow your models to understand relations structure

Comment: At the moment, through Policy.  Vendor_id is in Policy Table, that's why I am only pulling items that where sold AND where itemable_type == Policy.

Comment: And what about Order? Just show your models with associations

Comment: Broke down and added a vendor_id to items table.  So that should help now.  Will update question to show DB and relationships.